# form initials do not show

Tags: python, django

i am trying to set the form initials for the sender field as the logged in user, and it does not show. i removed the if request method statement and adjusted the indentaion and the initials showed. I am stuck, i believe the form is supposed to have that request method statement. i've gone through the documentation and it says the post method binds the data and submits, but there isn't any data when the page is refreshed or newly loaded. what could be wrong?

views.py

```
def transfer(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
 

    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TransferForm(request.POST,initial={"sender": profile})
    
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form)
            form.save()
            
            
            
            sender = models.sendcoins.objects.get(sender=request.user.profile)
            profile2 = Profile.objects.get(username=receiver)
            user_wallet = wallet.objects.get(owner=profile)
            print(receiver)
            temp = sender # NOTE: Delete this instance once money transfer is done
            
            receiver = models.wallet.objects.get(owner=profile2) # FIELD 1
            transfer_amount = sender.amount # FIELD 2
            sender = models.wallet.objects.get(owner=profile) # FIELD 3

            # Now transfer the money!
            sender.balance = sender.balance - transfer_amount
            receiver.balance = receiver.balance + transfer_amount

            # Save the changes before redirecting
            sender.save()
            receiver.save()

            temp.delete()  # NOTE: Now deleting the instance for future money transactions
        else:
            return(HttpResponse("form is not valid"))    

    else:
        form = TransferForm()
    return render(request, "sendcoins.html", {"form": form})
```

Comment: In the else condition you never set the initial (`form = TransferForm()`)...

Comment: It worked. I tried it before and it didn't work. Thanks